# How to set the default permission value for an APP in android?

Tags: android, permissions

I'm new to Android, and currently I'm doing a project which is related to camera. This APP will require the permission to access to the Cameras. I was thinking that if I can set the default value of the permission to be "yes", so that when the APP is launched for the first time, the window for asking permission will not show up.

Comment: Wouldn't defeat the purpose of asking for permission?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is setting the `tagetSdk` to less than 23. This will make the Google Play app to show all the permissions to the user before installation, which is quite annoying. It can't be done just for a single permission.

That being said, I advice against this: users prefer to be asked for permission beforehand, and having to accept lots of permissions during installation time without knowing the reason scares users, passing on installing your app.